# Why $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,\infty) $ cannot be extended to a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is a continuous function from $(0,\infty) $ to $\Bbb{R}$.

But why it cannot be extended to a continuous function from $[0,\infty)$ to $\Bbb{R}$ ?

Like there exists no $c \in \Bbb{R}$ such that by defining $f(0) = c$, I can make $\frac{1}{x}$ a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$.

The limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}$ does not exist, and I think that is not a sufficient condition to show that the function cannot be extended continuously?

Comment: In your case, it is enough to argue that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x$ does not converge.

Comment: So does that mean that it is sufficient that if limit desnot doesnot exist at $0$,then it cannot be extended continuously?

Comment: If $g$ is such an extension then we have $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x > 0$, and since $g$ is continuous at $0$, we must have $g(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^+}g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$. But the latter limit does not exist. Alternative proof: if $g$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, then it's certainly continuous on $[0,1]$, and therefore it must be bounded on $[0,1]$. But that's clearly not the case if $g(x) = 1/x$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: You have the answer in your last line with minor edit: the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}(1/x)$ does not exist and that's a sufficient condition to show that the function $1/x$ can not be continuously extended to $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{x}$ does not exist as a real number is enough to state that $\frac{1}{x}$ cannot be continuously extended to $[0, \infty)$.

If you work in the extended nonnegative real numbers $[0, \infty]$ equipped with the induced order topology from $\mathbb{R}$, then the function can be made continuous by defining $f(0) = +\infty$.

Comment: Also, it is important to note that $1/x \to \infty$ as $x \to 0^+$, so the limit **exists** if you want to work in the affinely extended real line. In general, if the limit does not exist in the topological space you are considering, then almost by definition (simply symbol-pushing) the function cannot be continuously extended to that point: Continuity at a point implies limit exists along every path.

Answer (score 0):

If you like, suppose it can be, so as you said, $f(0)=c$. Then let $\epsilon=c$. It suffices to show that for any $\delta $ there exists $x<\delta$ with $1/x>2c$.